# Is there are way to improve json deserialization when running the first time?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have an object tree which is serialized using JSON.

When running the deserialization (using Newtonsoft JSON.net) the first time it takes significantly longer then running it the 2nd time.

I guess its because the deserializer classes are jitted by the json framework I am using. I have no proof for this guessing.

Is there a way to improve the 1st deserialization run somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of frameworks, especially those that do serialization and deserialization, need extra time to initialize, and you can't change that. I think it's not the JIT that you observe, serializers usually compile classes on the fly and that takes more time than JIT-ting. What you can do is initialize them as early as possible. So for example serialize some sample objects as soon as your application starts.

In the case of ASP.NET, this point may not be the Application_Start event because it runs when the first request comes in. If you have lots, really *lots* of requests, this may be too late. There is support for a cache warm-up though: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx . Cache warm-up is entirely reasonable stuff if you need to be fast.